# What does the status "CG" mean in SLURM?

Tags: jobs, slurm

On a SLURM cluster one can use `squeue` to get information about jobs on the system.

I know that "R" means **r**unning; and "PD" meaning **p**en**d**ing, but what is "CG"?

I understand it to be "canceling" or "failing" from experience, but does "CG" apply when a job successfully **c**loses? What is the **G**?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

"CG" stands for "**c**ompletin**g**" and it happens to a job that cannot be terminated, probably because of an I/O operation.

More detailed info in the [Slurm Troubleshooting Guide](https://slurm.schedmd.com/troubleshoot.html#completing)

Answer (score 19):

I found this in the ['squeue' section](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html#SECTION_JOB-STATE-CODES) of the Slurm Troubleshooting Guide:

> state
>
> Job state, extended form: PENDING, RUNNING, STOPPED, SUSPENDED,
> CANCELLED, COMPLETING, COMPLETED, CONFIGURING, FAILED, TIMEOUT,
> PREEMPTED, NODE_FAIL, REVOKED and SPECIAL_EXIT. See the JOB STATE
> CODES section below for more information. (Valid for jobs only)
>
> statecompact
>
> Job state, compact form: PD (pending), R (running), CA (cancelled),
> CF(configuring), **CG (completing)**, CD (completed), F (failed), TO
> (timeout), NF (node failure), RV (revoked) and SE (special exit
> state). See the JOB STATE CODES section below for more information.
> (Valid for jobs only)